Issues with VMT (vtable) reading as DLL inside executable
im learning about vmt hooking and have some issues.
when i did this inside my executable it showed correct address
of the function.
Code:
    Obj* obj = new Obj;
     
    std::uintptr_t* vmt = *(std::uintptr_t**)(obj);
     
    printf("0x%llx\n", vmt[0]);

but now i have tried doing this by injecting my dll into the executable created by me like that:
and it prints weird address like this:
Hello in first function, 0x000001CCDA662210
??_7Obj@@6B@ -> 0x7ff678043008
vmt[0]: 0x244c894838ec8348

Code:
    std::uintptr_t address = ( ( std::uintptr_t )GetModuleHandleA( NULL ) + 0x3008 );
     
    printf( "??_7Obj@@6B@ -> 0x%llx\n", address );
     
    std::uintptr_t* vmt = *(std::uintptr_t**)( address );
     
    printf( "vmt[0]: 0x%llx\n", vmt[ 0 ] );

IDA Reversal:
Code:
    .rdata:0000000140003008 ; const Obj::`vftable'
    .rdata:0000000140003008 ??_7Obj@@6B@  dq offset sub_140007390 ; DATA XREF: sub_140007130+1D↓o
    .rdata:0000000140003010                 dq offset sub_1400073C0
    .rdata:0000000140003018                 dq offset sub_1400073E0
    .rdata:0000000140003020                 dq offset sub_140007400
    .rdata:0000000140003028                 align 10h


Sorry if im asking stupid things but i want to learn not copy and paste.

Right, 0x244c894838ec8348 doesn't look like an address. But it does look like x64 machine code: sub rsp,0x38 \ mov [rsp + ???],rcx

Yes, @harold. I want to get the function address, not the instruction. I don't know how to get the address of function from VMT.

Since you got code instead of the address of the code, it seems to me that you should remove one level of dereferencing, specifically vmt = *(std::uintptr_t**)( address ) should be vmt = (std::uintptr_t*)( address ), as address is already the address of the vtable (but as an uintptr_t so we do need to cast it, but not dereference it)

Okey it is working correctly, I am now able to call it from the vtable but I want to Shadow VMT Hook it. Im doing this like that but has some issues like the hooking doesn't occur and the DLL crash/freeze.
Code and output here as i cant post it here.
https://justpaste.it/fxv5r

If I read that correctly (some declarations are missing), you're making a copy of the vtable, changing an entry, and then you assign the address of the copy into the first slot of the actual vtable. Doesn't make sense.

I want to do Shadow VMT Hooking so instead of hooking like a function in the vtable we just replace the whole vtable if i understood that correctly and I don't know how to do it. The code I used was on some tutorial on YouTube about swapping vtable's. Can you point to me how to fix this? Also I have updated the code on the website with missing things.

That's fine but then you need to write the address of the new vtable into the object whose vtable you want to change. The vtable itself doesn't know who points to it.

Can you show me an example how? Based on my code please. I have some issues with fundaments of the C++ and want to learn them but I don't understand fully what you're saying.

In your first piece of code, obj is a pointer that points to the object. You dereferenced it and got the address of the vftable. In your second piece of code, address is already the address of the vftable, so you don't need to dereference it again
